# How can SQL Server display '€' and '¤' in the same varchar column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, character-encoding

I am currently working with a SQL Server Database (Locale: `German` , Collation:  `SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS` ).

Analyzing a conversion error, I noticed that some entries containing '€' and some entries containing '¤' are displayed in the same column.

The column is defined as `varchar(50)`.

Example result set:

```
Column
-----------
2€
-----------
41¤
```

This behaviour is odd since `varchar` character encoding is ISO 8859-1 which does not contain '€'. (**Answer by Larnu: This assumption is wrong**)

Apparently '¤' was replaced with '€' in most ISO 8859-1 applications in 1999 or most applications are now using ISO 8859-15.

If '¤' was replaced with '€' how can both be displayed in the same `varchar` column?

I did not find a lookup table for `SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS` or article describing which character was replaced instead of '¤'.

Comment: *"This behaviour is odd since varchar character encoding is ISO 8859-1"* This is wrong. `varchar` uses the related code page to the collation you are using, and the collation `SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS` has mappings for both the characters `€` and `¤`.

Comment: Thanks for claryfing, where can I look up the Collations character encoding?

Comment: @Ricardo, `SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY('SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS', 'CodePage');` returns 1252. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"This behaviour is odd since varchar character encoding is ISO 8859-1"* This is wrong. `varchar` uses the related code page to the collation you are using, and the collation `SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS` has mappings for both the characters `€` and `¤`.

You can get the code page for a collation by using the `COLLATIONPROPERTY` function. For the one in your question that's Code Page 1252:

```sql
SELECT [name],
       COLLATIONPROPERTY([name],'CodePage') AS CodePage,
       Description
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
WHERE [name] = N'SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS';
```

And a quick [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=characters+in+codepage+1252) brought me to this [page](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/windows-1252/list.htm), which shows that both `'€'` and `'¤'` are in that code page, with the byte encodes `80` and `a4` respectively.